# Dynamically add a keypress handler to an input

Tags: jquery

I want to dynamically add a keypress handler to an input.

```js
$("#m1rename").click(function() {
  $('#modalinput').val('').keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.keycode === 13) {
      renameabc();  // this function name should be changed dinamically, based on `m1rename` click.
    }
  });
});

function renameabc() {
  alert('abc');
}

function renamedef() {
  alert('def');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='modal'>
  <form id='modalform' autocomplete='off'>
    <input type='text' id='modalinput'>
  </form>
  <div class='modalbtn' id='modalok' onclick=''>OK</div>
  <div class='modalbtn' id='modalcancel' onclick=''>CANCEL</div>
  <div class='clear'></div>
</div>
```

I want the alert to be shown if the Enter key is pressed inside `modalinput`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: You have no `#m1rename` element, so the click handler to attach the keypress handler will never run.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I have `m1rename` element, off course. It's on the top menu, but it's not important for my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dynamically add a key press listener to your input you can do like this:

```
$("#m1rename").click(function() {
  var funcName = $(this).val(); //this takes the value from m1rename. Use .text() if .val() don't work.
  $('#modalinput').val('').keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.keycode === 13) {
      funcName();  // this function name should be changed dinamically, based on `m1rename` click.
    }
  });
});

function renameabc() {
  alert('abc');
}

function renamedef() {
  alert('def');
}
```

Comment: Zorken17. I want to do it dinamically, i.e. attached function name will be changed by clicking on m1rename. Pls see my update.

Comment: But you need to tell us what m1rename is. Is i a button, dropdown or what? What value do you want dynamically, is it a property from m1rename or what?

Comment: button m1rename is on the top of page in navigation bar. It is the same for all pages. But clicking on it I need to change `function which is attached` to modalinput onkeypress event. Sometimes it is `renameabc()` sometimes `renamedef()` etc

Comment: but, value or text of `m1rename` is not subject of change. It is a button or a div.

Comment: Yes, but if you can read code you will see that I save the text och value of m1rename and the call the same function as the text or value of m1rename

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133327/discussion-between-zorken17-and-bonaca).

Answer (score -2):

try below code its working fine when you press enter key in textbox then it displays alert message.

```
    <html><head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#modalinput").keypress(function(e) {
 if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    alert("You pressed a key inside the input field");
}
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='modal'>
<form id='modalform' autocomplete='off'>
<input type='text' id='modalinput'>
<div class='modalbtn' id='modalok' onclick=''>OK</div>
<div class='modalbtn' id='modalcancel' onclick=''>CANCEL</div>
<div class='clear'></div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can it useful? ask me if you need any help

Comment: sunil, I want to do it dinamically, i.e. attached function name will be changed by clicking on `m1rename`.

Comment: now it press enter key based on the id of the input box

Comment: please ask me if you  have any query

Comment: i will help you

Comment: sunil, you don't understend my question, pls read it carefylly.

Comment: m1rename is important?id of the textbox also change when m1rename press?

Comment: no, just attached function name is subject to change.Sometimes it is `renameabc`, sometimes `renamedef`...

Comment: my code works on input textbox id if you press enter key in the textbox then it displays alert message.but i can't understand how the functions are dynamically pass

Comment: button `m1rename` is on the top of page in navigation bar. It is the same for all pages. But clicking on it I need to change function which is attached to `modalinput` onkeypress event.